# Accessing SSRS reports from Angular Using ngx-ssrs-reportviewer

Tags: angular, reporting-services, .net-core, ssrs-2016

I have an angular 6 application with .Net core. To show SSRS (2016) report, I used ngx-ssrs-reportviewer library but it gave me error of access rights on report server so I got access into report server and problem solved because it uses Windows Authentication. But we cannot do it always because we cannot provide every user with access to the server and not all users are on intranet. Can someone help me to resolve this issue? As per library's documentation, impersonation is an option but I want someone to guide me how to do that exactly in Angular application.

Comment: Maroof, have you found a solution? I have the same issue. The library documentation states: "You could also configure your application to use Impersonation to pass the necessary credentials to your report", but like you I have not found any examples of how to do this.

Comment: No, fortunately my client is going to use the application within organization (intranet application) using windows credentials.